# How to filter data on Object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object, filter

I get data from backend with this function

```
  private loaddata(): void {
    this.dataService.loaddata().pipe(
      tap((response: any) => {
        this.persons = response.results;
        this.personmembertrue = this.persons.filter(x => x.is_family_member === 'false')
      }),
      takeUntil(this.onComponentDestroy)
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

and `console.log(response)` show JSON like below

```
{
    "count": 38,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 113,
            "foreigner": false,
            "outside_community": false,
            "nipt": "",
            "nid": "G45675570K",
            "is_family_member": true
        },
        {
            "id": 115,
            "foreigner": false,
            "outside_community": false,
            "nipt": "",
            "nid": "K30776771A",
            "is_family_member": false
        },
        {
            "id": 116,
            "foreigner": false,
            "outside_community": false,
            "nipt": "",
            "nid": "J305070577",
            "is_family_member": false
        }...
      ]
    }
```

What I want are data that have `"is_family_member": false`, for this I create `this.personmembertrue = this.persons.filter(x => x.is_family_member === 'false')`

this part of code show empty.

Any idea please how to show data with `"is_family_member": false`

Comment: The string `'false'` is truthy while the boolean `false` is not. You don't need the equality check in the condition: `this.personmembertrue = this.persons.filter(x => !x.is_family_member)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the condition to:

```
this.personmembertrue = this.persons.filter(x => x.is_family_member === false);
```

See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

We can even simplify @Zunayed Shahriar expression with that

```
this.personmembertrue = this.persons.filter(x => !x.is_family_member);
```

EDITED: It will only work if is_family_member is always either true/false as mentionned @Zunayed Shahriar in comment.

Comment: It will also work. But if the field is nullable and is null then the data will also be filtered. If the user only wants data where the field is not null and false then this expression won't be accurate. Right?

Comment: Yes you are right :) I edited my answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using only ==, with 3 = you compare type and value, or try removing quotes, probably you are comparing bool with string.